# no_proxy Proxy support in Chef

Tags: proxy, chef-infra

Chef has support for proxy server see for example http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/chef/Chef/HTTP/BasicClient#http_client_builder-instance_method

This client `http_client_builder` will for example be used by `remote_file`.

As documentation shows there is no support for `no_proxy` sites.

So if one want to combine remote_file resources from sites before and behind the proxy server there is a problem. Chef cannot do both. One cannot combine `remote_file` resources that are before and behind proxy server. There is no way to tell Chef that a configured proxy server should not be used for certain sites. There is no `no-proxy` setting.

What is the best practice to deal with this issue in Chef? There are some suggestions to unset proxy server before resources that are not accessible through the proxy server. But these all do not work. See for example https://serverfault.com/questions/498683/one-off-use-of-http-proxy-in-a-chef-remote-file-resource

Should one split all recipes that have `remote_file` resources before and after proxy server?

That way we have two types of Chef runs. One for recipe that use proxy server one for recipes that should not use a proxy server?

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. Please check the source code.

See: https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/http/basic_client.rb#L114-L117